# Alterar campo input file

Tags: php, input, sql-update

Estou tendo um problema no meu arquivo de alteração de arquivos `pdf`. Eu só queria que alterasse quando o campo `input` file for preenchido.

> não está apresentando nenhum erro, só que quando eu edito o
>   formulário, e não preencho nada no input = file ele retira a url salva
>   no banco e salva como '/upload'.

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
$postador = $_POST['postador'];

if(empty($_FILES['arquivo_alteracao'])){


$sql_query = "UPDATE posts SET titulo = '$titulo', descricao = '$descricao', data = NOW(), hora = NOW(), postador = '$postador' WHERE id = '$id'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_query);

if($resultado === TRUE){
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable'>
                        <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
                        ID: $id Editado com Sucesso!</div>";

    header("Location: ../prof-ADM/lista_conteudo.php");
}  else {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                        <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
                        Erro ao Editar ID: $id</div>";
    header("Location: ../prof-ADM/editar_conteudo.php");
}
} else {

$arquivo_alteracao = $_FILES['arquivo_alteracao']['name'];

//Substituindo os caracteres especiais
$original = 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜüÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûýýþÿRr"!@#$%&*()_-+={[}]/?;:,\\\'<>°ºª';
$substituir = 'aaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooouuuuuybsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooouuuyybyRr                                ';

$arquivo_alteracao = strtr(utf8_decode($arquivo_alteracao), utf8_decode($original), $substituir);

//Substitui os espaços em branco
$arquivo_alteracao = str_replace(' ', '-', $arquivo_alteracao);

//Substitui os Maiúsculos por Minúsculos
$arquivo_alteracao = strtolower($arquivo_alteracao);

$caminhofinal = 'upload'.'/'.$arquivo_alteracao;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo_alteracao']['tmp_name'],$caminhofinal);

$sql_query = "UPDATE posts SET titulo = '$titulo', arquivo = '$caminhofinal', descricao = '$descricao', data = NOW(), hora = NOW(), postador = '$postador' WHERE id = '$id'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_query);

if($resultado === TRUE){
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable'>
                        <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
                        ID: $id Editado com Sucesso!</div>";

    header("Location: ../prof-ADM/lista_conteudo.php");
}  else {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                        <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
                        Erro ao Editar ID: $id</div>";
    header("Location: ../prof-ADM/editar_conteudo.php");
}
}
```

Não sei se minha lógica está certa. Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Qual o erro que está apresentando?

Comment: não está apresentando nenhum erro, só que quando eu edito o formulário, e não preencho nada no input = file ele retira a url salva no banco e salva como '/upload'.